# How to provide if and else Formatter in Devxpress Gridcontrol using Xaml?

Tags: xaml, devexpress, gridcontrol

I am developing an app using Devexpress Gridcontrol using Xaml. In a cell Template i am having a Textblock in which i want to Display 'Open' if the value in Binding is '0' and 'Close' if it is '0'. Can this be done using `FormatterString` ie. Using `FormatStringConverter`?

Comment: So you want it to display Open AND Close if it is 0? Or is there a typo in your question? Also, are you talking WPF, SL? If it's returning null you can just specify a `TargetNullValue` in the Binding Base, or if it's 0 you can do it with a `DataTrigger` & `ChangePropertyAction` without even a converter.

Comment: I am sorry my question was wrong. Actually it should be like 'Open' if the value in the binding is '0' and 'Close' if it is '1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. :)

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"


<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Value="0" Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=Self}">
        <im:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text"
                                         Value="Open"/>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
    <ei:DataTrigger Value="1" Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=Self}">
        <im:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text"
                                         Value="Close"/>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: No problem, glad you got your fix. :)